# Use Raw FTP commands to upload file

Tags: ftp

I need to upload a file using Raw FTP commands in my program. I got downloading to work using RETR, but how do I upload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the STOR command for that. You will also need PORT or PASV with STOR to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer..You have to use the STOR command followed by the file. F.e. "STOR test.txt"