# Send Close File Signal to FTP Server

Tags: c++, file-upload, ftp

I am implementing FTP Client in C++ using Windows Sockets. I have successfully connected to Server on Port 21, and transmitted the file in PASV mode using "STOR Sample.txt" command on the data port. The problem is that I am unable to tell the server about transfer completion (I want to send the signal to close data connection) so that i can receive the "226 Transfer OK" from the server on my control connection.

Further, I am not receiving anything from the server via recv(). I think that is because server is still listening on the data connection.

Comment: Just close the data connection?

Comment: which command do I send to close the data connection?

Comment: closesocket? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: closesocket worked ... I received "226 Transfer Ok" on my control connection

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
[proper user of STOR command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624613/proper-user-of-stor-command)

You get back the port to connect to when you send PASV and then you tell the server where to store the data using STOR and the you connect to the port the PASV command returned and send the data - when you are done you close this second socket and continue sending commands with the original one.